# Django Inline Admin : Error : <class 'ui.models.License'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'ui.models.Car'>

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following models :

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...
    some attributes
    ...

class Person(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)

class License(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

The models are a bit abstract at the moment. I plan to detail them out later.

In my `admin.py` I have the following code:

```
class PersonInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Person

class LicenseInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = License

class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PersonInline,
        LicenseInline
]

admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)
```

It was working good when only `Person` was inline. When I added `License` it throws me this weird error:

```
<class 'ui.models.License'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'ui.models.Car'>
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong. Please help.

UPDATE:

This maybe useful :

Inititally `License` did not have a `Foreign Key` on `Car`. But then i added it. And only after that I have done the `Inline` in `admin.py`

I have also done `python manage.py syncdb` and a server restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[syncdb does not detect changes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) (read the section **Syncdb will not alter existing tables**) .

You either need to
 - Drop the database and recreate (not very recommended) or 
 - Install a 3rd party app called [django-south](http://south.aeracode.org/) to modify the database colums and manage the migrations

Comment: have you created a migration and run it ?

Comment: One way to verify it is, go to `./manage.py dbshell` and do `desc <tablename>` to see if the foreign key field is created

Comment: I dropped the table from the db. and ran `python manage.py syncdb` and it worked. Awesome! Thanks and kudos!